# Combobox.Text.Equals Not Testing Expected Value

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am currently modifying an existing application, I am removing the old UI elements and replacing them with standard WinForms components. So this code is functional as it appears.

My code is passing the conditional IF check when it should not be. The text for each of the comboboxes is `<Any>` by default, so they should skip past the encapsulated code.

(When filters are selected, they replace the default text to select the correct parts of SQL query to return results)

Now for the bizarre part!
The text property is coming up as `System.Data.DataRowView` for some of my combobox.text. Originally, this happened for all of them but now the first check appears as `<Any>` as intended. (Although I didn't change anything at all)

[image: Screenshot of problem]

As you can see in this screenshot of my code during debug. The pinned value of `cbRegGroup.Text` is `System.Data.DataRowView` but when I enter the list of properties and scroll down to the text property it is shown as `<Any>`.

I have cleaned and rebuilt my project... and consulted with a college but neither of us can work out why text value is appearing like a .ToString()'ed object.

I am at a loss at what to do next. Any suggestions?

```
    private void LoadPupilView()
    {
        try
        {
            this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

            dgMain.Rows.Clear();
            //now populate list view
            String filter = "[surname] LIKE '" + SearchString + "%'";
            if (!cbYearGroup.Text.Equals("<Any>"))
            {
                String YearGroupCode = null;
                try
                {
                    YearGroupCode = cbYearGroup.SelectedValue.ToString();
                }
                catch { }

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(YearGroupCode))
                    filter = filter + " AND [yearGroup] LIKE '" + YearGroupCode + "'";
            }

            if (!cbRegGroup.Text.Equals("<Any>"))
            {
                String RegGroupCode = null;
                try
                {
                    RegGroupCode = cbRegGroup.SelectedValue.ToString();
                }
                catch { }

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(RegGroupCode))
                    filter = filter + " AND [registrationGroup] LIKE '" + RegGroupCode + "'";
            }

            if (!cbHouse.Text.Equals("<Any>"))
            {
                String HouseGroupCode = null;
                try
                {
                    HouseGroupCode = cbHouse.SelectedValue.ToString();
                }
                catch { }

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(HouseGroupCode))
                    filter = filter + " AND [houseGroup] LIKE '" + HouseGroupCode + "'";
            }

            DataRow[] dataRows = tblPupils.Select(filter);
            foreach (DataRow datarow in dataRows)
            {
                dgMain.Rows.Add(new object[] { 
                    datarow[0].ToString(),
                    datarow[1].ToString() + " " + datarow[2].ToString(),
                    datarow[5].ToString(),
                    datarow[4].ToString(),
                    datarow[6].ToString(),
                    datarow[3].ToString()
                });

            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error : " + err.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        }


    }
```

I'm very interested in knowing why this seems to be inconsistent... why is the first conditional check passed? When the rest aren't although they are the same.

Comment: It's also not recommended to have empty `catch` blocks.  Doing so swallows exceptions.

Comment: @BryanCrosby Thanks but I am aware of that leaving them empty was a bad habit of our ex-developer I have a lot of them to change!

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `DisplayMember` property of the `ComboBox` to the name of the column you want to display.

Comment: These where already set, but it made me learn what they actually control which is always good to know. Plus ruling this out led me to the actual solution, which involved tweaking the plugin we use to communicate with the database service. So thank you :)